# How to Encode Tags Entities with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace, innerhtml, html-entities

How to encode Tags with .innerHTML

array encode html entities

Does not work well

```
var find = ['<','>','"'];
var replace = ['&lt;','&gt;','&quot;'];

window.onload = function() {
    var code = document.getElementsByTagName("code");
    cl = code.length;

    for (var e = 0; e < cl; e++) 
         code[e].innerHTML = code[e].innerHTML.replace(find,replace);
};
```

Comment: That's nice. Did you have a question? Oh, and you forgot `&`. That needs to get encoded as well...

Comment: yes this is question!

Comment: use .textContent instead

Answer (score 1):

You're safer creating a text node. Any needed escapes will be done for you:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var code = document.getElementsByTagName("code");
  cl = code.length;

  for (var e = 0; e < cl; e++) {
    var tx = code[e].innerHTML;
    code[e].innerHTML = "";

    var n = document.createTextNode(tx);
    code[e].appendChild(n);
  }
};
```

```html
<p><code>Escaped: <b><i>foo</i></b></code></p>

<p>Not: <b><i>foo</i></b></p>
```